# mongodb Callback inside for loop in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback

I'm trying to fill up mongoDB collection with the data from Excel. I think I understand the asynch nature of callback and therefore have localized the scope using another function before the database callback. However, I'm unable to get past my error.

Here is the code.

```
var http = require('http');
var parseXlsx = require('excel');
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var faker = require('faker');
var moment = require('moment');
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var uristring =
    process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
    process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
    'mongodb://localhost:27017/loadmongo/data';


var db = mongo.db(uristring, {native_parser:true});

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log('connected');


});

http.createServer(function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');

parseXlsx('userRegistration.xlsx', function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;


    console.log(data.length);
    console.log(data[0][0]);    

    for(var i = 0; i<= data.length; i++) {

        //(function(i){
        console.log('inside for loop');
        var t = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        var aCD = moment().subtract('days', t).format('MM DD YYYY');
        var tmpID = new ObjectID();
        console.log(data[i][0]);
        var tmp = {
                '_id': tmpID,
                'firstName': data[i][0],
                'lastName': data[i][1],
                'email1': data[i][2],
                'email2': data[i][3],
                'accountCreationDate': aCD,
                'location': {
                    'country' : data[i][9],
                    'city' : data[i][6],
                    'state' : data[i][7],
                    'stateCode' : data[i][7],
                    'zipcode' : data[i][10],
                    'streetName' : data[i][5],
                    'streetNumber' : data[i][4],
                    'countryCode' : data[i][8],
                    'longlat': {
                        'type' : "Point",
                        'coordinates': [data[i][12], data[i][11]]
                    }

                },
                'serviceNeededCurrent': {

                },
                'serviceOfferedCurrent': {

                },
                'serviceCompleted': {

                },
                'reviewsGiven': {

                },
                'reviewesRecieved': {

                },
                'financialRecords': {

                }
        };

        (function(tmp){
        db.collection('userRegistration').insert(tmp, function(err, result){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log('some error')

            }

            if (result)
                console.log('userRegistration Collection.. Done');


        }); 

        }(tmp));
    } //end of for loop


    }); // End of parsexlsx
```

and here is the output

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/
675
Ernesto

C:\workspace\workspace1\loadmongo\node_modules\excel\node_modules\node-promise\promise.js:204
          throw error;
                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at C:\workspace\workspace1\loadmongo\hello-world-server.js:43:22
    at C:\workspace\workspace1\loadmongo\node_modules\excel\excelParser.js:156:3
    at Object._onImmediate (C:\workspace\workspace1\loadmongo\node_modules\excel\node_modules\node-promise\promise.js:164:27)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:336:15)
```

Comment: It seems to be just a problem with your parseXlsx method, doesn't it? Nothing to do with Mongo, I suppose... Your line 43 is `console.log(data[0][0]);`, isn't it? Are you sure of your file path?

Comment: You think ? but, look at the output 675 is the output for console.log(data.length); and Ernesto is the output of console.log(data[0][0]);. Also, when I removed the whole for loop and the database call, I do not see the error.

Comment: I also noticed, despite seeing the error, db is all filled up correctly. Still cannot figure out the reason for error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh sorry I didn't realize that those were the outputs of your 2 `console.log`! Ok you just have to stop your loop before `data.length`!

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
```

Arrays indexes range from `0` to `<arrayLength>-1` ;)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, I'm trying to think why my code did not print the contents of the for loop till the error ?